# Cumulative Value summed up with first entry of a column with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, point, addition

I have got the following dataframe:

```
lst=[['01012021','A',100,'NaN'],['01012021','B',120,'NaN'],['01022021','A',140,5],['01022021','B',160,12],['01032021','A',180,20],['01032021','B',200,25]]
df1=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['Date','FN','AuM','NNA'])
```

I would like to generate a new column (AuM_2) which takes the starting value in column AuM and accumulates the entries in column NNA by the column Product. The end result should look like the below mentioned dataframe:

```
lst=[['01012021','A',100,'NaN','NaN'],['01012021','B',120,'NaN','NaN'],['01022021','A',140,5,105],['01022021','B',160,12,132],['01032021','A',180,20,125],['01032021','B',200,25,157]]
df2=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['Date','FN','AuM','NNA','AuM_2'])
```

Do you have any idea how I could generate column AuM_2 with groupby?
Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum values from [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) and first values per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df1['NNA'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['NNA'], errors='coerce')
df1['AuM'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['AuM'], errors='coerce')

g = df1.groupby('FN')
df1['AuM_2'] = g['NNA'].cumsum() + g['AuM'].transform('first')
print (df1)
       Date FN  AuM   NNA  AuM_2
0  01012021  A  100   NaN    NaN
1  01012021  B  120   NaN    NaN
2  01022021  A  140   5.0  105.0
3  01022021  B  160  12.0  132.0
4  01032021  A  180  20.0  125.0
5  01032021  B  200  25.0  157.0
```

Comment: Thank you jerael. Your code gives the desired output. I also will have to to the same task, without grouping. It means that the column FN will be deleted. I tried the following code:

Comment: df1['AuM_2']=df1['NNA'].cumsum()+df1['AuM'].transform('first') However I got the following error: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'   Do you have any ideas how I could resolve this problem?

Comment: @Bsleon - use `df1['AuM_2']=df1['NNA'].cumsum()+df1['AuM'].iat[0]`

Comment: Hi jezrael. I tried to apply your code on my real dataframe: `iVV_Product_Changes['Bestand_iVV_NoMarktEinfl']=g['Neugeld_M'].cumsum()+g.transform('first')` Unfortunatelly, the following error arises: "Concatenation operation is not implemented for NumPy arrays, use np.concatenate() instead. Please do not rely on this error; it may not be given on all Python implementations." Do you have any idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: @Bsleon - you forget for column name `g.transform('first')`, need `g['AuM'].transform('first')`

Comment: You are corrrect. thank you. Now, I would like that the first value it starts counting isn't the first row with value 100 (AuM), but let's say the 5th row. is this possible with groupby?

Comment: @Bsleon - I think best is create new question.